# End-user fillout form dropdown instead of checkbox for Group(s)

Tags: groups, forms, newsletter

Using Civicrm version 4.6.11, WordPress 4.4.2
I've created a fill out form that allows our site visitors to sign up for an email newsletter. One of the required fields is the Group (core) field (using the predefined Goup(s) from backend Profile set up. The selection option defaults to check boxes allowing users to choose more than one group. We need them to be able to select one and only one group membership. The group field is one of the core fields rather than a custom field. Is there a way to either change the check boxes to select or radio or is there a way to use a custom field that will populate the core field of Group(s)? We need the user selection to apply to the primary group(s) that we have set up in the civicrm backend that we then use for specific email lists.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Not sure if it's the best way, but it works. I use a script and put the checkboxes inside a table with the  using the class called in the script:

```
<td class="example">
<input type="hidden" name="group[11]" value="" />
<input class="example"  skiplabel="1" id="group_11" name="group[11]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
Utility Advocate
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
jQuery(":checkbox").on('click',function(){if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){jQuery('td.example :checkbox').prop("checked",false);jQuery(this).prop("checked",true);}});
</script>
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution, please, I would love it hear it. : )